# How to execute exe in VSTS Release pipeline empty process

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have .Net Solution project it has multiple projects few of them are console application. I want to execute one of the console application during my release pipeline as task under empty process.

How can I refer the .exe from my build artifact?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add "Command Line" task during the release pipeline, in the "Tool" field specify the .exe of the console application from your artifact location, for example: `"$(Agent.ReleaseDirectory)\Tools\ConsoleApp.exe"`.

[image]

Comment: And how would  you upload a console app into that folder?

Comment: You should include the app in the Artifacts.

Comment: Thanks - the problem is that this app is not really a build artifact, its a static executable, not related to the repo & solution I am building....

Comment: So maybe store it in a git repo, and add a command line step that do git clone.