# Upload custom exe to Azure Devops pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I'd like to execute a command line app that I created as part of my CI builds.

**The command line app is not related to the repository on which the build is running.** (Basically, its a tool that is supposed to send some project related metadata to a company web application to gather some metrics).

It seems I can execute it using a Command Line task, as explained here:
[How to execute exe in VSTS Release pipeline empty process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52353490/how-to-execute-exe-in-vsts-release-pipeline-empty-process)

The question is, however - **how do I upload my custom tool into Azure Devops**?

I know it's possible to create custom tasks (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/add-build-task?view=azure-devops) , but it seems quite a lot of effort to create, especially given that I have a console tool that is doing what I need.

Comment: Uploading the tool itself in your custom extension is **not** a recommended practice. Instead, consider creating a "Tool Installer" task that would download and install the tool on the agent as appropriate. One example of this is the [Java Tool Installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/java-tool-installer?view=azure-devops) or the [Chocolatey installer (GitHub source included)](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DavidGardiner.chocolatey-tool-installer-task)

Answer (score 0):

I do this by including a seperate deployment folder in the git repo with my source code. This folder contains all the extra stuff (exe's) that I need to call to deploy.

You could if you wanted keep these artifacts in a different repo and/or different artifact if you wish as you can get any number of different artifacts

Then I include the deployment folder when publishing artifacts. In your build step you pull down the artifacts and it includes your EXE.

You're meant to be able to use things like [NPM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/npm?view=azure-devops) to install helper libraries on the fly but none of my required libraries were ever supported.

You can also use a self hosted agent which is your own host (Often an Azure VM). You install everything you need on there then you install a DevOps self hosted agent which lets build pipelines use it.

Comment: Thanks. This exe is not a part of the repository that I am building, so I guess it's not really a build artifact - rather a static executable. 
But fair point about using a private build agent - that's what I am actually doing, so I just need to make sure that my exe is located properly on the build VM.

Comment: I can't check now but I'm pretty sure the build step can get artifacts from multiple repositories. But yes if you're already using a build agent then just set it up there.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a build of your exe
2. Upload your exe to blob storage.
3. Create a SAS token to access your blob.
4. In your build create a task with a PowerShell script. In the PS script download your exe (unzip), and copy it to Build.StagingDirectory/"yourToolFolder". Then in your PS script run it. You probably want to pass it arguments like the location of the repo on the build agent.

Answer (score -1):

A way to achieve this involve create a deployment group and add a server to the group where you have access and privileges to upload your console. it could be onprem or cloud depends in your requirements.